# Trouble understanding loops and arrays

Tags: arrays, loops, pascal, procedure

How would I change the following procedure so that it uses a loop, with the loop controlled by the number at the start of the file? I would also like to add a fixed sized array of records to store each record read.  I am relatively new to all of this so any help is appreciated.

```
procedure ReadLinesFromFile(var myFile: TextFile);
    var p: Person;
        number: Integer;
    begin
     ReadLn(myFile, number);
     ReadLn(myFile, p.name);
     ReadLn(myFile, p.age);
     ReadLn(myFile, p.name);
     ReadLn(myFile, p.age);
     ReadLn(myFile, p.name);
     ReadLn(myFile, p.age);
     ReadLn(myFile, p.name);
     ReadLn(myFile, p.age);
     ReadLn(myFile, p.name);
     ReadLn(myFile, p.age);
    end;
```

Comment: Why have you posted this from a different account than your other q posted at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to declare an array, such as

```
people: array [1..100] of person
```

Then fill it in the following manner

```
 ReadLn(myFile, number);
 for i:= 1 to number do
  begin 
   ReadLn(myFile, people[i].name);
   ReadLn(myFile, people[i].age);
  end;
```

It would be better to use a dynamic array as the above code assumes that there are upto 100 records in the file. There is also no check made as to whether the file actually contains 'number' records. These are left 'as an exercise for the reader'.